# How does the Hamiltonian operator contain the angular momentum operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, angular-momentum, hamiltonian, commutator

The time-dependent Schrödinger equation is
$$
\hat H \Psi = i\hbar \partial_t \Psi
$$
When solving this equation for the hydrogen atom (in position space) by separation of variables, one gets not only the the eigenvalues of the hamiltonian (i.e., possible energies), but also the quantum numbers $\ell$ and $m$, which are related to the eigenvalues of the angular momentum operators $\hat L_z$ and $\hat L^2$, though they were not used explicitly. Does $\hat H$ somehow *contain* those operators ? and if not where do $\ell$ and $m$ come from ?

Since the eigenstates of $\hat L_z$ and $\hat L^2$ are *degenerate* wrt those of $\hat H$, I thought they cannot be found so explicitly (except by a very happy coincidence!)

Comment: I think this is a homework level question, as the answer is given in any good quantum mechanics textbook.

Comment: What is the homework ? Not every two operators $A$ and $B$ that commute $[A,B]=0$ are such that $A = cB + E$, but this Hamiltonian, may every other Hamiltonian, is such that $\hat H = c\hat L^2 + \cdots$, and you can't tell until $\hat H$ and $\hat L^2$ are represented in the position space or some other space

Comment: What you wrote above about operators doesn't make sense or at least requires more explanation. The conservation of angular momentum in atoms has to do with spherical symmetry - whether you describe it in classical or quantum way (remember Kepler laws?)

Comment: I restate here: if $A$ and $B$ are such that $[A,B] = 0$ it doesn't follow that $A = cB+\cdots$. But $\hat H$ is such that $\hat H = c\hat L^2+\cdots$, without $[\hat H,\hat L^2] = 0$. It depends on the dots, i.e. the potential $V(\mathbf r)$, whether $[\hat H,\hat L^2] = 0$ holds or not

Comment: Angular momentum appears in the kinetic part of the Hamiltonian - just write it in spherical and cylindrical coordinates. You can even add the magnetic field - it is also homework stuff, it is covered in the chapter on the Zeeman effect.

Comment: Homework guy...

Comment: I am not flagging your last comment and I am not downvoting you, despite your reluctance to do basic research in the textbook.

Comment: @Vadim Just because something can be found in a text book does not mean it is a homework question. The site policy on homework questions says nothing about that.

Comment: @BioPhysicist Fisrt of all thanks to those who voted to reopen the question and those who answered. I didn't know at the time of posting the question that $\hat H = c\hat L^2+\cdots$. The answer below from JEB notes that part, but I hoped for more mathematical explanation, (I knew at that time that commutating observables can be simultaneouosly diagonalized) What I really want about these operator stuff is the mathematical rigor

Answer (score 3):

When operators commute there exists a basis of common eigenvectors. Since for the hydrogen atom $\hat H$ commutes with $\hat{L^2}$ as well as a component of $\hat{\mathbf L}$ (that we usually take to be $\hat L_z$) we know that there is a basis of common eigenstates to all three operators.

Answer (score 2):

The topic of what is "in" the hamiltonian for the hydrogen atom:

$$ \hat H = -\frac{\hbar^2}{2\mu}\nabla^2 - \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r} $$

is a big topic.

It is invariant under rotations and can separated in spherical coordinates, with:

$$\nabla^2 = \frac 1 {r^2} \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\big(r^2\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\big) - \frac 1 {\hbar^2 r^2}\vec L^2 $$

This leads to the $l$ quantum number and the S, P, D, ... shells solutions. Since $[L^2, L_z]=0$, the representation theory of SO(3) naturally leads to the integer $m$ quantum numbers with bound $|m| \le l$. Rotational invariance means the $m$ are degenerate for fixed $l$.

The hydrogen hamiltonian is also separable in parabolic coordinates because the hamiltonian commutes with the (classically conserved) Runge-Lenz vector:

$$ \vec A = \frac 1 2(\vec p \times \vec L - \vec L \times \vec p) - \frac{\mu e^2 \vec r} r$$

This amounts to a hidden SO(4) symmetry and is the reason the $l$ are degenerate so that the energy only depends on $n$. (The classical counter part is that orbit energy does not depend on eccentricity, rather it only depends on the semi-major axis).

It's all in $\hat H$.

Comment: I think the radial term of the Laplacian you've written isn't correct. Shouldn't it be $$\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right)?$$

Comment: $$
\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\right) \iff \frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}r
$$
can you prove it ?